# React & Jest: Unable to find an element after wrapping with act

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I am currently learning how to test React component using Jest. I created a simple Login Form and write the below test.

```
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import "@testing-library/jest-dom";
import { LoginForm } from "./login-form";
import { act } from 'react-dom/test-utils';

describe("LoginForm", () => {
    it("should render", () => {
        // GIVEN

        // WHEN
        render(<LoginForm />);

        // THEN
        expect(screen.getByText("Sign In")).toBeInTheDocument();
    });

    it("should execute submit on button click and valid input", () => {
        // GIVEN
        const onSubmit = jest.fn();

        // WHEN
        render(<LoginForm onSubmit={onSubmit} />);
        screen.getByText("Sign In").click();
        
        // THEN
        expect(onSubmit).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

After I run using Jest, it shows passing tests.

```
 PASS  src/app/login/login-form.spec.tsx
  LoginForm
    ✓ should render (22 ms)
    ✓ should execute submit on button click and valid input (35 ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        0.638 s, estimated 1 s
```

Interesting thing is that there is a warning above the pass message that I should wrap using `act(...)`.

```
Warning: An update to LoginForm inside a test was not wrapped in act(...).
    
    When testing, code that causes React state updates should be wrapped into act(...):
    
    act(() => {
      /* fire events that update state */
    });
    /* assert on the output */
    
    This ensures that you're testing the behavior the user would see in the browser. Learn more at https://reactjs.org/link/wrap-tests-with-act
```

Then I tried wrapping the code using `act(...)` according the link, like below

```
import { act } from 'react-dom/test-utils';

//////
    it("should execute submit on button click and valid input", () => {
        // GIVEN
        const onSubmit = jest.fn();

        // WHEN
        act(() => {
            render(<LoginForm onSubmit={onSubmit} />);
            screen.getByText("Sign In").click();
        });

        // THEN
        expect(onSubmit).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
```

It suddenly fails with below output,

```
LoginForm
    ✓ should render (22 ms)
    ✕ should execute submit on button click and valid input (2 ms)

  ● LoginForm › should execute submit on button click and valid input

    TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an element with the text: Sign In. This could be because the text is broken up by multiple elements. In this case, you can provide a function for your text matcher to make your matcher more flexible.

    Ignored nodes: comments, script, style
    <body>
      <div />
    </body>

      22 |         act(() => {
      23 |             render(<LoginForm onSubmit={onSubmit} />);
    > 24 |             screen.getByText("Sign In").click();
         |                    ^
      25 |         });
      26 |
      27 |         // THEN
```

Why it happened, what did I miss, and how to fix this?

**Update 1**

I tried removing L23 per @tomek-buszewski's suggestion. But still the similar error output

```
    TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an element with the text: Sign In. This could be because the text is broken up by multiple elements. In this case, you can provide a function for your text matcher to make your matcher more flexible.

    Ignored nodes: comments, script, style
    <body />

      21 |         // WHEN
      22 |         act(() => {
    > 23 |             screen.getByText("Sign In").click();
         |                    ^
      24 |         });
      25 |
      26 |         // THEN
```

Comment: `act` should wrap actionable lines, so I would suggest moving line 23 out of it and leaving just the clicking part (L24).

Comment: @TomekBuszewski I tried it. still the same result :/ "TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an element with the text: Sign In."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out adding `waitFor` will remove the warning. The below answer works

```
    it("should execute submit on button click and valid input", async () => {
        // GIVEN
        const onSubmit = jest.fn();

        // WHEN
        render(<LoginForm onSubmit={onSubmit} />);
        await waitFor(() => screen.getByText("Sign In").click());

        // THEN
        expect(onSubmit).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
```

https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async/#waitfor

> When in need to wait for any period of time you can use `waitFor`, to wait for your expectations to pass.